# Nested Dictionaries to CSV with non-uniform (malformed?) data using dictwriter

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I'm currently building my data into a nested dictionary due to the way the data is entered and later used, but I wish to write a readable "Summary" csv in this intermediate step for tracking purposes.  It's my understanding that Dictionaries are non-ordered, but it seems when I use these dictWriter functions, the order seems to matter.

I can't copy my exact code onto this computer, but this is what my data structure looks like

```
myItems = 
    {
    "Item1": 
        {
            "Col1":"c1.1",
            "Col2":"c2.1",
            "Col3":"c3.1",
        },
    "Item2":
        {
            "Col1":"c1.2",
            "Col3":"c3.2",
        },
    "Item3":
        {
            "Col1":"c1.3",
            "Col4":"c4.3",
            "Col5":"c5.3",
        },
    "Item4":
        {
            "Col3":"c3.4",
            "Col2":"c2.4",
            "Col1":"c1.4",
        }
    }
```

I'd like my table to look as follows (Without extra spacing, doing that for readability)

```
Item, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
Item1, c1.1, c2.1, c3.1
Item2, c1.2,     , c3.2
Item3, c1.3,     ,     , c4.3, c5.3
Item4, c1.4, c2.4, c3.4
```

I COULD write a function that indexes through the dictionaries, assembles known headers, convert it to a list, entering blank entries where keys aren't represented, etc etc but it would seem that Dictwriter would have some form of accommodating these sorts of situations by virtue of being designed for unordered writing.

Plus, if such a way exists, I'd be able to use it elsewhere in my program to print out summaries of SQL Database entries that may not share the same tables.

I'm still fairly new to Python, so I'm hearing about how powerful these nested dictionaries can be, so if I was oversold on the power of nested dictionaries I blame their cheerleaders if this is not possible.  =P

Comment: `DictWriter` already knows how to handle missing keys. The `restval` parameter (defaults to the empty string, `''`) is used as a default value to write to the CSV column if a key is missing.

Comment: Note that `DictWriter` takes a *sequence of fieldnames*, which is an *ordered* data structure, which is then used to determine the order of the columns being written. You then either give the `DictWriter` a single row at a time (an ordered operation, one call after another) or a *iterable* of rows (using `.writerows()`), which again is an ordered operation. So `DictWriter` solved this by having you, the programmer, supply the ordering.

Answer (score -1):

DictWriter's default is to use blanks for missing keys.  If you iterate over your items and create a dictionary that is a copy of the original with the `Item` key added, you'll get the result you want.  `fieldnames` must also be specified to provided the column write order.

```
import csv

myItems = {'Item1': {'Col1':'c1.1',
                     'Col2':'c2.1',
                     'Col3':'c3.1'},
          'Item2':  {'Col1':'c1.2',
                     'Col3':'c3.2'},
          'Item3':  {'Col1':'c1.3',
                     'Col4':'c4.3',
                     'Col5':'c5.3'},
          'Item4':  {'Col3':'c3.4',
                     'Col2':'c2.4',
                     'Col1':'c1.4'}}

with open('out.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames='Item Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5'.split())
    w.writeheader()
    for k,v in myItems.items():
        D = v.copy() # So myItems is not modified.
        D['Item'] = k
        w.writerow(D)
```

Output:

```
Item,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
Item1,c1.1,c2.1,c3.1,,
Item2,c1.2,,c3.2,,
Item3,c1.3,,,c4.3,c5.3
Item4,c1.4,c2.4,c3.4,,
```

Note that `utf-8-sig` is the best encoding if Excel will be used to read the file.  It supports Unicode correctly, although in this case only ASCII-compatible characters were used:

[image: Excel image of opened CSV file]